# How to separate price from numbers in wit.ai or any other ai platform

Tags: artificial-intelligence, wit-ai

We are trying to build a bot by using wit.ai  When we ask for price, we have to force users to type $ to separate the answer from general numbers. For example, when we are how much do you want to pay? The users answer:"100"  The 100 will not be treated as price, but regular numbers. How to solve this issue in wit.ai or other ai platforms?

Comment: well, can't you just convert user's input number to "$100" or "100 dollars" depending on user's session state before calling runActions?